# Polymer: Correctly remove polymer element whith elements inside it

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I have a polymer element which has a costum element inside it. I want to remove everything (parent and child) when I click on it.

The problem is that every time I close an instance of the parent element I get an error. I think it's related to the fact I'm removing an element that has an element inside.

How can I remove it correctly?

Here's the method code:

```
closeWindow: function (event, detail, sender) {
    this.firstChild.remove();
    this.remove();
}
```

Here's the error I'm having:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Here's an image of the error:

[image: An image of the error]

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that shows off this behavior?

Comment: What's wrong with just `this.remove()`?

Comment: Good news!! with the new release (0.2.4) this error seems to be solved

Comment: Interesting, I have a same problem. It doesn't seem to me that it has been resolved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue was fixed a few releases ago and should also work fine in Polymer 0.3.x onwards. If you run into any further issues with `this.remove()` within the scope of an element, please file an issue.

Answer (score 0):

On `polymer 1.5.0+` you do `event.target.remove()`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14492912)

Comment: I think it does answer the question